# How can I use jsonpath in python to change an element value in the json object

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I have the following json object (Say car_details.json):

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "age":30,
   "cars":
   [
     {
       "car_model": "Mustang",
       "car_brand": "Ford"
     },
     {
       "car_model": "cx-5",
       "car_brand": "Mazda"
     } 
}
```

I want to change the value of car_model from cx-5 to cx-9 through python code. 
I am providing the json path to this element, through an external file. The json-path expression is basically represented as a string. Something like this:
'cars[2].car_model'
And the new value is also provided through an external file as a string:
'cx-9'

Now how do I parse through car_details.json using the jsonpath expression, and change its value to the one provided as string, and finally return the modified json object

P.S I want to do this through python code

Comment: Use the [python json module](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+json+module&oq=python+json+mo&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2656j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach without using json module. Load your data in variable. Then iterate over cars key/values. If you find the key that is the value you are looking for set it to new value.

Also note: you need to close your array block, otherwise your above json is not valid. Generally I use an online json parser to check if my data is valid etc. (may be helpful in future).

```
data =     {
       "name":"John",
       "age":30,
       "cars":
       [
         {
           "car_model": "Mustang",
           "car_brand": "Ford"
         },
         {
           "car_model": "cx-5",
           "car_brand": "Mazda"
         } 
       ]
    }

for cars in data['cars']:
    for key, value in cars.items():
        if key == "car_model" and value == "cx-5":
            cars[key] = "cx-9"
print(data)
```

If you want to load your json object from a file, let's assume it is called "data.json" and is in the same directory as the python script you are going to run:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

for cars in data['cars']:
    for key, value in cars.items():
        if key == "car_model" and value == "cx-5":
            cars[key] = "cx-9"

print(data)
```

Now if you'd like to write the content to the original file or new file, in this case I am writing to a file called "newdata.json":

```
import json
import re

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print(data)

with open('external.txt') as f:
   content = f.read()
   print(content)

for cars in data['cars']:
    for key, value in cars.items():
        if key == "car_model" and value == "cx-5":
            cars[key] = content 

with open('newdata.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: I think I should have been more clear. This is my case: I have a file " "car_details.json" which is basically the json object that I want to parse for elements and update them. I have another file: "request_change.json" which contains details about the jsonPaths to the elements that are to be changed in car_details.json and their corresponding values...  "request_change.json" looks something like this: {"testcase_ID":"test_1A","description":"Some description","request_change_data":[{ "element_path": "[cars][0][car_model]", "element_value": "cx-9"}]} (Contd....)

Comment: Contd... Now i'll have to read "request_change.json", get the element_path and element_value from there (which are represented as a string), use this element_path and parse through car_details.json and change its value to the value of "element_value"

Comment: Can you please post an example of the request_change.json file you are going to read in.

Comment: It looks like this: { "testcase_ID":"test_1A","description":"Some description","request_change_data": [ { "element_path": "[cars][0][car_model]", "element_value": "cx-9" } ] } ...